# How to undo bundle exec rake assets:precompile or make it faster?

Tags: asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

I ran `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` in order to solve the Webpack error referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62239847/12625913).

Then when I load localhost:3000, it takes forever to load.  How can I undo this, or make it faster to load?

ps This is my first question on SO so let me know if I should add something.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this issue out. For some reason I had a server port running in the background that was slowing this down.  I used

`lsof -nP +c 15 | grep 3035`

to find what was running there, and then found the PID.

Then I used

`kill -9 <PID>`

to kill it. After that, I restarted my server and it ran smoothly!